# Make div stick to bottom of another div (not bottom of viewport)

Tags: css

How can I make a div stick to the bottom of the parent div, not necessarily the bottom of the viewport? I still want to place content below the parent div.

I'd like to do this with cross-browser compatibility and no JS if possible.

Comment: I only upvoted because I hate people that downvote for no reason.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Read up about css position: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Basically you can position a div with absolute anywhere within a parent that has position relative.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy, use flexbox

Example here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWGvJR

You use

```
display: flex;
```

on the container.
The you set the element you want to fill the space to

```
flex-grow: 1;
```

Hope that helps. No JS highly compatible ([flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

Comment: does this work with older browsers? It seems pretty new: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: Not for ie9 or below. It currently has about 80% global compatibility : http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Yep, ie9 is 1.14% and ie8 1.45% of users, flexbox's partial support is 94% too, which covers this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

position the footer(or div) absolute, with a fixed height. give the container padding equal to the height of the footer.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z47o6p3x/1/

html

```
<div class="container">
    <footer>bottom content</footer>
</div>
<p>additional content</p>
```

css

```
.container {
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.container footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: I don't want this to be a footer. I want content below the div. Won't absolute make it stick to the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: it will stick to the bottom of the closest 'position:relative' parent. which is why .container has 'position:relative'. you will still be able to put content below container without a problem. ill update the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z47o6p3x/1/